# Python igraph density function for directed graphs

Tags: python, igraph, directed-graph

Does python igraph function 'G.density()' calculate the density for an undirected graph only? I want to calculate the density for an directed graph. Must I divide by 2? There is an option for 'loop'=True or False but there is no option for directed or undirected graph. I know that for an undirected graph, the density is

```
2m/n(n-1)
```

while for directed graph it us

```
m/n(n-1)
```

I am not seeing anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is [there](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#density):

```
 g.density(loops=False)
```

The important part comes in defining your graph object `g` as directed or undirected. The `density()` method will take that into account for your computation